# How do I create an empty Guava ImmutableList?

Tags: java, generics, guava, immutablelist

I can create a [Guava `ImmutableList`](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/23.0/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/ImmutableList.html) with the `of` method, and will get the correct generic type based on the passed objects:

```
Foo foo = new Foo();
ImmutableList.of(foo);
```

However, [the `of` method with no parameters](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/23.0/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/ImmutableList.html#of--) cannot infer the generic type and creates an `ImmutableList<Object>`.

How can I create an empty `ImmutableList` to satisfy `List<Foo>`?

Answer (score 47, accepted):

If you assign the created list to a variable, you don't have to do anything:

```
ImmutableList<Foo> list = ImmutableList.of();
```

In other cases where the type can't be inferred, you have to write `ImmutableList.<Foo>of()` as @zigg says.

Answer (score 18):

`ImmutableList.<Foo>of()` will create an empty `ImmutableList` with generic type `Foo`.  Though [the compiler can infer the generic type](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29776623/722332) in some circumstances, like assignment to a variable, you'll need to use this format (as I did) when you're providing the value for a function argument.

Comment: @Robino Sure, but that's because I answered my own question immediately. ColinD's answer was still helpful and I thought valuable.

Answer (score 3):

Since Java 8 the compiler is much more clever and can figure out the type parameters parameters in more situations.

Example:

```
void test(List<String> l) { ... }

// Type checks in Java 8 but not in Java 7
test(ImmutableList.of());
```

#### Explanation

The new thing in Java 8 is that the [target type](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/genTypeInference.html#target_types) of an expression will be used to infer type parameters of its sub-expressions. Before Java 8 only arguments to methods where used for type parameter inference. (Most of the time, one exception is assignments.)

In this case the parameter type of `test` will be the target type for `of()`, and the return value type of `of` will get chosen to match that argument type.